# Network setting - weird routing

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have D-Link DIR-615 as my Wi-Fi router.
And I have a very weird routing.

My router IP is `192.168.1.1`, my PC IP is `192.168.1.128` and my phone IP is `192.168.1.19`. I have enabled DDNS to access my PC from phone - `myname.dlinkddns.com` and I have setted up virtual server like this:

```
Public port: 64000
Private port: 3389
Private IP: 192.168.1.128
Protocol: TCP\UDP
Interface: All
```

But problem is: I cannot connect to my PC from phone, when phone is in Local Network. I can ping it, but I cannot access it. When I switch my phone to use cell data, I can easily access my PC via `myname.dlinkddns.com:64000`.

When in LAN, I cannot access to PC via `192.168.1.1:64000` nor `myname.dlinkddns.com:64000`. What's my problem and how to fix that?

From PC and phone I can easily navigate to router's main page via `myname.dlinkddns.com` or `192.168.1.1`. I guess there's something wrong in virtual server setup... Any ideas?

Comment: All IP are bind to MAC-addresses, so they're static.

Comment: Binding an IP address to a MAC address has nothing at all to do with whether or not an IP address is static. A static IP address is one that is manually configured in a device instead of being assigned automatically by DHCP. I think you mean that the devices use DHCP reservation to get IP addresses.

Comment: Vladislav, what you describe is called [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) - allowing two devices behind the same NAT to communicate using their external addresses. Check whether your device supports this technology.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) - allowing two devices behind the same NAT to communicate using their external addresses. Check whether your device supports this technology.

> When in LAN, I cannot access to PC via 192.168.1.1:64000 nor myname.dlinkddns.com:64000. What's my problem and how to fix that?

You can't access it via `myname.dlinkddns.com:64000` because it is an external address and apparently hairpinning is not supported or not enabled on you router.

You can't access it via `192.168.1.1:64000` because your router is listening on port `64000` on it's external interface. `192.168.1.1` is an internal interface of your router.

> What's my problem and how to fix that?

If you can't get hairpinning to work, then just use internal address and port of your PC when you are on your local network: `192.168.1.128:3389`. Use DDNS name and external port `64000` when you are outside of your local network.